# Seekbar databinding error

Tags: android, seekbar, android-databinding

Getting the following error when compiling:

```
BindingAdapter onOpacityValueChanged(android.widget.SeekBar,int,boolean): old values should be followed by new values. Parameter 2 must be the same type as parameter 3.
public  void onOpacityValueChanged(SeekBar seekBar,  int newOpacity,  boolean fromUser) {
             ^
```

XML code is:

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/soaring_forecast_seekbar_opacity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:min="0"
        android:onProgressChanged="@{forecastDisplay::onOpacityValueChanged}"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/soaring_forecast_constraint_layout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/soaring_forecast_constraint_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/soaring_forecast_image_time"/>
```

and  source code is:

```
@BindingAdapter(value={"android:onProgressChanged"})
public void onOpacityValueChanged(SeekBar seekBar,  int newOpacity,  boolean fromUser) {
    forecastOverlayOpacity = newOpacity;
    appPreferences.setForecastOverlayOpacity(newOpacity);
    stopImageAnimation();
    displayForecastImageSet();
}
```

From what I can see the code matches to SeekBarBindingAdapter onProgressChanged. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

> From what I can see the code matches to SeekBarBindingAdapter
> onProgressChanged. What am I missing?

- You can check the source code of [SeekBarBindingAdapter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/3b920788e90bb0abe615a5d5c899915f0014444b/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/android/databinding/adapters/SeekBarBindingAdapter.java)

###OR

- You can see in Android Studio libraries.

[image]

> BindingAdapter
> onOpacityValueChanged(android.widget.SeekBar,int,boolean): old values
> should be followed by new values. Parameter 2 must be the same type as
> parameter 3. public  void onOpacityValueChanged(SeekBar seekBar,  int
> newOpacity,  boolean fromUser) {
> ^

###@BindingAdapter methods must be static.

###Most Important

The way you are following is not correct. `@BindingAdapter` are used where you need some custom implementation. See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters).

So remove `@BindingAdapter(value={"android:onProgressChanged"})` from your method.

Or you can make your method even more simple by using lambda expression.

```
public void onOpacityValueChanged(int newOpacity) {
//something
}
```

and

```
android:onProgressChanged="@{(sb, value, fromUser)->forecastDisplay.onOpacityValueChanged(newValue)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I see I was over complicating this. I didn't need the //@BindingAdapter(value={"android:onProgressChanged"})

What worked was:

```
//@BindingAdapter(value={"android:onProgressChanged"})  <- Don't need.
public void onOpacityValueChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int newOpacity, boolean fromUser) {
    forecastOverlayOpacity = newOpacity;
    appPreferences.setForecastOverlayOpacity(newOpacity);
    stopImageAnimation();
    displayForecastImageSet();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare the seekbar as globally

```
SeekBar myseekBar;
```

In OnCreateView :

```
myseekBar =  findViewById(R.id.myseekBar);
myseekBar.setProgress(1);
myseekBar.setMax(10);
myseekBar.incrementProgressBy(1);
```

It will partition the seekbar in 10 points scale each will be 1 point scale valued apart..

```
myseekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
    {
       // get progress here
    }
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
});
```

From xml :

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/myseekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/SplashScreen"
    android:progressTint="@color/BlueText"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
```

This is how seekbar is displayed, initiated , and can be accessed via xml and code

Hope it helps