# Databinding with SeekBar's onProgressChanged not working

Tags: android, data-binding

I am using Seekbar with DataBinding and below is my code

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="generatePasswordModel"
        type="android.account.model.GeneratePasswordModel" />

</data>

 <SeekBar
       android:id="@+id/sbPasswordLength"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onProgressChanged="@{generatePasswordModel.onValueChanged()}"
       android:max="20"
       android:min="4" />
```

and Model class is below

```
data class GeneratePasswordModel(
    private var seekValue: String,
    private var seekDisplay: String
) : BaseObservable() {


    var mSeekDisplay: String
        @Bindable get() = seekDisplay
        set(value) {
            seekDisplay = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.mSeekDisplay)
        }

    fun onValueChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, progresValue: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
        mSeekDisplay = progresValue.toString()
    }

}
```

But I am getting following error while build an apk

```
ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1/Users/amitsiddhpura/Documents/.../app/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/.../android/DataBinderMapperImpl.java:18: error: cannot find symbol


                                                 import android.databinding.ActivityGeneratePasswordBindingImpl;
22:40:06.432 [ERROR] [system.err]                                         ^
22:40:06.432 [ERROR] [system.err]   symbol:   class ActivityGeneratePasswordBindingImpl
```

Comment: had you tried clean and rebuild? I think the class has not been found

Comment: Yes, I have tried so many times even restarted Android studio but things not working

Comment: andorid:onProgressChanged is not found everything is founded

Comment: ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1/Users/amitsiddhpura/Documents/.../app/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/.../android/DataBinderMapperImpl.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
 This is also new for me

Comment: try click on File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Invalidate and Restart

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem with onValueChanged method, but on the class ActivityGeneratePasswordBindingImpl class generation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the top answer on this question: [Seekbar databinding error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52080871/seekbar-databinding-error)

It appears that you need to specify the arguments in your XML:

```
android:onProgressChanged="@{(seekBar, value, fromUser)->generatePasswordModel.onValueChanged(seekBar, value, fromUser)}}
```

But, since you're not actually using the `seekBar` or the `fromUser` in your Kotlin code, you could modify your function's definition like so:

```
fun onValueChanged(progresValue: Int) {
        mSeekDisplay = progresValue.toString()
    }
```

And then the XML would look like:

```
android:onProgressChanged="@{(seekBar, value, fromUser)->generatePasswordModel.onValueChanged(value)}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jacob, yes now it's working fine :)